# Is there something that prevents a multithreaded C# compiler implementation?

Tags: c#, compiler

The C/C++ language family apparently has multithreaded compiler implementations that work on file level parallelism, but the Microsoft C# compiler (csc.exe) is single-threaded only.  MSBuild supports multithreaded building, but only at the project level, and obviously dependency projects have to be compiled before the projects that depend on them so there are practical limits to parallelism.

Is there a multithreaded C# compiler that I'm not aware of?  If not, is there something about the C# language specification that prevents a multithreaded C# compiler, or is it just "hard" and therefore not worth it?

Comment: Could you precisely name the multithreaded C++ compiler implementations you are alluding to?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch probably just referring to `make -j`

Comment: MSBuild is the equivalent of `make -j`, so I am also interested what this multi threaded C++ compiler is. As far as I am aware, neither GCC nor Clang is internally multi threaded.

Comment: BTW see also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/322494/7043

Comment: It would be helpful if you could a) name that compiler you are talking about and b) describe how *exactly* it is multi-threaded. Otherwise all answers will just be stumbling blindly in the dark. How can we compare how the C♯ compiler does multi-threading with how your C/C++ compiler does multi-threading if you don't tell us how it does it? I'm also curious to know which compiler you are talking about, because there is, in fact, a [so] question about multi-threaded C/C++ compilers, and the consensus seems to be that there aren't any! The closest thing is a comment that says that the Digital …

Comment: … Mars **linker** (*not* compiler) may or may not be multi-threaded.

Comment: And `gold` *linker* on Linux *is* also multi-threaded.

Comment: The Microsoft C++ compiler with the /MP switch parallelizes over all the source files you give it, doing the work properly parallel build systems do for other compilers, because MSBuild's parallelism story is essentially completely broken.

Comment: Incredibuild is a good example of a multi threaded c++ compiler. Not only does it run as much threads as you have cores on your own machine, but it can even go as far als distributing build tasks over the network to other machines. It can crunch a two hour build down to 15mins if you use it in a company with 50 computers in the network. Very powerfull tool.

Comment: Wait, to elaborate: incredibuild is not really multithreaded but multi-process. In that it will spawn as many processes as you have cores, each running a single thread. But I don't think that difference is relevant in this case. (Is it?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct answer is almost certainly "because the current state of multi-threading is already adequate for the task."  Or, if you like, "because the costs of providing additional multithreading exceed the benefits."

As you already know, implementing multiple threads in a program doesn't guarantee a speed improvement.  Threads have overhead, so unless the performance improvement is greater than the overhead, it's not worth it.  Using too many threads can actually slow down a program.  If the program is I/O bound, the optimal number of simultaneously running threads is probably the number of processor cores (8 in my computer, if you count the hyper-threading as separate cores), but you still need a way to break the work into individual units first.

Because the Roslyn compiler is written in C#, [it can take advantage of the Task Parallel Library to parallelize some tasks](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/20/10-questions-10-answers-on-roslyn.aspx):

> Both the native compilers and the Roslyn compilers are primarily single-threaded, but the higher-level pieces of Roslyn, such as the language services, take advantage of the Task Parallel Library (TPL) for multi-threading when calling the compiler APIs. For example, Visual Basic and C# methods are essentially standalone once parsed and can be compiled in parallel under Roslyn.

Comment: I've been using VS2013 and Roslyn comes standard in VS2015.  You can download and use Roslyn in VS2013 with a NuGet package so tried rebuilding my 21-project solution.  The original rebuild time is about 30 seconds, but the new rebuild time with Roslyn is a little over 60 seconds.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me.  C++ has a primary emphasis on performance, and "you don't pay for what you don't use," so the picture is a bit more complicated than just adding threads.

Comment: I think this hints at an answer: "Visual Basic and C# methods are essentially standalone once parsed and can be compiled in parallel under Roslyn."  A full answer needs to explain what about C# makes further parallelism impractical.  @Euphoric suggests it's a "web of references" but I'd like some more explanation.

Comment: A "web of references" is the `using` statements at the top of each C# file, referencing various external .NET libraries and classes in the .NET Framework.  In C++, this sort of code is already incorporated into each class file with includes.  So basically you're trading one problem for another.

Comment: I think you may have meant to say "CPU bound", not "I/O bound".

Comment: @oldfart: Could be.  Last time I tested this was on a utility I wrote that processed very large data files.  I assumed that I was I/O bound because I was reading data as fast as the interface would allow, but perhaps I was actually CPU bound and didn't know it.

Comment: If something is CPU bound, it means that each thread will saturate one core.  So increasing the number of threads to match the number of cores is useful.  If something is I/O bound, then throwing more threads at it may help because it overlaps the I/O operations.  In this case, the optimal number of threads is mostly unrelated to the number of cores.  Once I/O becomes bottlenecked, throwing more threads at it won't help.

Comment: @OldFart: `Once I/O becomes bottlenecked, throwing more threads at it won't help.` -- Exactly my situation.

Answer (score 7):

One could imagine a parallel compiler. For example, one could imagine a compiler which would compile several functions (in the same source file) in parallel.

Remember that a compiler is not mostly a parser. Practically speaking, an industrial strength optimizing compiler is spending most of its time *transforming some internal representations* of the compiled source code because optimizations are done by transforming internal representations. So each function that occurs in the source code could in theory be compiled somehow separately (for simple tasks like constant folding, common sub-expression elimination, etc.) and only later on you would merge their representations.

The reason why nobody is coding a parallel multi-threaded compiler is that there is no substantial theory supporting such a design, so you need to start the entire design and implementation of the compiler from scratch. That is possible, but is really too costly.

Remember that *industrial strength compilers are large pieces of software*, typically several millions lines of source code. It is difficult to afford rewriting all of them, given that the design of such a parallel compiler is not known, and you cannot predict how much you would gain.

> The C/C++ language family apparently has multithreaded compiler implementations

<sup>(I believe you are wrong, or confusing the builder program -e.g. `make` on Linux- with the compiler proper -e.g. `cc1plus` started by the `g++` command -often started by `make`...- on Linux with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))</sup>

BTW, I never heard of a multithreaded C++ or C compiler. All the ones I know (notably Clang & GCC) are purely sequential, mono-threaded, programs (and they are very large beasts, GCC having more than dozen millions lines of source code). What is somehow able to run in parallel -in several processes, not threads- is some steps of whole program optimization (often called *link-time optimization* i.e. LTO that is `g++ -flto -O2` for GCC, but that LTO is still done by the compiler). But your builder (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) started as `make -j`) would be able to run several compilation processes (working on different translation units) in parallel. Also, the GNU [`gold` linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) *is* multi-threaded. And link-time optimization is rarely used (and not always worth the cost, e.g. `g++ -O2 -flto` would often gain only less than 5% of performance w.r.t. `g++ -O2`) because it slows down the compilation time significantly (e.g. doubles it).

PS: In 2019 it is rumored that recent Go compilers are multi-threaded. But GCC 9 is still mono-threaded.

Comment: I think you get parallelism in C/C++ because each file can be compiled to a .obj file in parallel, and then you need a linker to combine them.  Strictly speaking, the compiler working on a single file isn't doing anything parallel, but the whole project is being compiled in parallel because each file is separately compiled (apparently because each file has a full reference of all its dependencies).  Products like IncrediBuild can get much more speed-up out of a C/C++ project than out of a C# project.

Comment: Yes, this is called LTO mentioned in my last sentence. But it is not at all multithreaded compiler. Feel free to cite counter-examples and references. And LTO is really slow at compile-time, so most people avoid it (when you use it, the practical gains are not that good, e.g. 5% ...)

Comment: Depends what you call compiler. If I have 200 source files to compile, I can run 200 single threaded compilers in parallel, or I can run one compiler that can compile 200 files in parallel.

Comment: For me the notion of compiler is self-evident (at least for every language implementation I saw or heard of). It is not an IDE, it is generally a command line program. So GNU `make` is *obviously* not a compiler, even if it is often starting several compilation processes in parallel.

Comment: Since you updated for 2019: you may want to read about recent improvements in LTO: http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2019/05/gcc-9-link-time-and-inter-procedural.html?m=1 - basically it is used also to reduce binary sizes, which can be significant

Comment: I know that already, but thanks for mentioning it. However, GCC 9 is still mono-threaded, even in 2019.

Answer (score 5):

It is not parallelized because it cannot be parallelized. C++ can be parallelized because the interface between files is hard-coded by programmer, so each file is perfectly isolated from all others.

But in C#, there is not such clear separation between files. Quite often, files have web of references, that are rarely clear. Even if it would be possible to parallelize something, it would be far from advantage that C++ gains from parallelism.

But C# doesn't really need parallelization. C++ need parallelization because each file is HUGE after includes happen, so compiling single file can take much more time than compiling C# file of similar complexity.

But C# projects are parallelized on solution level. If you have two projects that don't reference each other, they can be built in parallel. So if you have solution with many projects and you keep the dependency tree relatively flat, it will compile many projects in parallel.

Comment: AFAIK, a given C++ compilation process has only one thread (in all the compilers I know). But you can have several compilation *processes* (at most, one per compilation unit) running in parallel.

Comment: Are you saying that granular C# solutions with uni-directional reference flow build faster than monolithic solutions?

Comment: @Den Probably not because the compiler doesn’t know this until it is compiled.

Comment: I noticed #include files being mentioned… I played with some rather large open source library written in C++, and using pre-compiled headers made a complete recompile about 4 times faster.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a multithreaded C# compiler that I'm not aware of? If not, is
>   there something about the C# language specification that prevents a
>   multithreaded C# compiler, or is it just "hard" and therefore not
>   worth it?

No, no, you're thinking about this the wrong way around. The C++ compiler does in parallel a thousand times as much work as the C# compiler does serially. There's no need to offer parallel C# compilation because C# compilation just isn't ridiculously over-expensive and with pointless inter-file boundaries. Furthermore, we *do* compile assemblies in parallel, which is much easier and more equivalent to what the C++ compiler does.

Fundamentally, C++ offers parallel compilation because C++ compilation is totally broken. C# compilation is not broken.

Comment: Well excuse me, but if I have a quad core processor, how could you say with a straight face there is no need to make compilation four times faster?

Comment: You can still compile four assemblies in parallel. C# code just doesn't take long enough to compile relative to how difficult it would be. You can get much more useful speed improvements with regular serial optimizations, not to mention better language features, more bugfixes, etc.

Comment: Quad cores have never made anything four times faster. That isn't how parallel processing works.  Even if perfectly the code perfectly takes advantage of the number of cores the work you're doing eventually demands to be put back together.  There are also costs to permitting parallel processing at all.  In the end this means you can't just blindly insist it would be faster if it was parallel.  Certain jobs are well suited.  Others aren't.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the C♯ language that would preclude a multi-threaded compiler implementation.

However, it's just not necessary.

Real-World programs consist of multiple independent components. You can compile these independent components independently, with independent compiler instances. Usually, there are more such individual components than there are CPU cores.

In fact, there are tools such as distcc or IncrediBuild whose purpose it is to distribute these independent compiler jobs across an entire cluster of machines. Now, if we already need to build clusters to be able to cope with the already existing process-level parallelism in compilers (or rather build systems), what do we need *even more* thread-level parallelism for?

Comment: I hope you're joking.  I have a solution with 21 projects and it takes 30 seconds for a rebuild all.  When I tried IncrediBuild it took 65 seconds, and their sales person said you wouldn't see an improvement with IncrediBuild unless you had many more projects in the solution.  Now 30 seconds isn't terrible, but using TDD my change-build-test loop itself takes 30 seconds even when it only has to build 2 large assemblies and about half that is build time but seems to be single-threaded.  If you *could* save time by throwing more threads at it, yes, Do IT!  Anything over 0.25 seconds is too long!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Fred Silberberg](https://github.com/333fred), an engineer on Roslyn, (the compiler of C# and Visual Basic) [on the .NET Discord server](https://discord.com/channels/732297728826277939/732297728826277942/884824841696464896):

> Roslyn is *highly* multithreaded. The immutable model the compiler uses was expressly designed for the purpose of being easy to scale out to as many cores as possible. The only single-threaded stage in the compiler is the last one, actually emitting bytes to disk. Not a heck of a lot we can do there.